# Dynamically update borderpane in JFX?

Tags: javafx

I added a borderpane which contains text to a javafx scene.

How do you update a scene in javafx ?

I would like to do this so that i can reflec the changes dynamically.

So a sample would look like this :

My gui : text

dynamic update

My gui : updated text

```
public class JFXPnlRef extends JFXPanel {
   public JFXPnlRef(){
      this.init();
   }
   private void init(){
       Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
       /* run gui main scene */
       Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run(){
               createScene();
           }  
       });
    }
    private void createScene(){
       /* we are in the JFX thread */
       /* set our look and feel style for the gui */
       borderPane = new BorderPane();
       final Text text = new Text();
       text.setFont(new Font(25));
       text.setText("javafx threads!");
       borderPane.setLeft(text);
       scene = new Scene(borderPane);
       this.setScene(scene);
    }
    public void myThread(){
        JFXPnlThrd.run( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Text text = new Text();
            text.setFont(new Font(25));
            text.setText("inside the thread!");

            scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable();
            Parent root = scene.getRoot();
            ObservableList<Node> i = root.getChildrenUnmodifiable();

            /* use the root node to add stuff to the border pane ? */

            revalidate();
            repaint();
            updateUI();
           }
       }); //end of thread
     }//end of method
}//end of class



/ * outter class to check  if we are in the javafx thread */
public class JFXPnlThrd {

     public static void run(Runnable task) {
       if(task == null) 
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                   "The task can not be null");
       if(Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) task.run();
       else Platform.runLater(task);
     }
}
```

Comment: Scene elements are updated automatically by JavaFX. You don't have to explicitly do anything for it. Just change the text of the `Text/Label` and it will the reflected. Just make sure all the changes are performed on the JavaFX Application thread.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this , and for the reply. I understand that it is best not to modify the scene elements elsewhere but the JFX App. thread. However , i am lost as to how I can do this. I will post a simple sample of my code , so perhaps i can get further guidance here. Thank you.

Comment: A sample code helps, but a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always better ;)

Comment: i just noticed your MCVE suggestion . of course i would notice after posting as fast as possible my sample code :( . poor me , too slow for the internet! okay i can look into MCVE. i am not going to lie, i am still getting accustomed to SO.

Comment: Your code seems alright to me. Every time you want to make some changes on the scene graph, you make sure it runs on the JFX application thread by calling `Platform.runLater()` . Does the code run as intended?

Comment: ItachiUchiha , one of the best characters in Naruto...just wanted to throw that out there.

Comment: My code runs, but i can not gain access to the border pane and add another text element dynamically. in specific, i know that "Parent root = scene.getRoot();" will get me the borderpane but after that i am stumpped.

Comment: Now, I understand where you are lost ;) My advice for you would be to first try native JavaFX applications before jumping into hybrid Swing-JavaFX apps. Nevertheless, you can always have a reference of your Text as a class instance, just like you have for your scene. Again, this becomes cumbersome if you have multiple controls.

Comment: Oh my gosh! it worked :D

Comment: I made my text a class wide variable which i labeled "private static Text text" and whala! Thank you so much! This was a hell-of-a learning experience for me. I want to mention that i did get access to the borderpane , but from there it seems near impossible to change it dynamically...

Comment: Why static? I cannot see any reasons as to why you need to declare your `Text` as static.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My code would not let me run without marking it static...

Comment: and now that i double checked...whoopsie...your right. it does not need to be static..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ItachiUchiha!

The answer was simple.

Move the local `Text` defined as

```
final Text text = new Text();
```

to a class instance variable

```
private Text text;
```